# Best Android Batch Testing Tool

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is that possible to run batch testing for the android application ? instead of using native emulator or genymotion because that is really need huge memory.

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "batch testing for the android application" means. If you do not want to use an emulator, use a device.

Comment: i mean, build apk - upload to (some testing tools, may be cloud or anything) - get the report test, the report may contain result test (from *dpi android device OR getting error after testing on device a,b and etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read a blog that listed android testing tools for high performance application testing so fast and also reduce memory consumption issues like android emulator.

some of most popular of them are:

1> OPEN Source : Robotium

https://github.com/robotiumtech/robotium

2> Testdroid : http://testdroid.com/

Read this blog :
http://www.testingtools.com/mobile-testing/

Comment: Thanks for your respon, i'm start digging that one "Robotium" but if you ever get experience with robotium i'm really appreciate that if you also want to share :)

Comment: Well actually I had discussed with one of my senior developer for your problem and he suggested this one so I forward it to u.. but you can always find guidelines and documentation on their official site. @anIndonesian

Comment: Please upvote answer or accept it if it's really helpful. @anIndonesian

Comment: This is helpfull, you got it man ! :) @tapan-parmar